# Can't consume from ActiveMQ with Spring Boot Web

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am having trouble getting messages from a locally run ActiveMQ. I can produce them onto the queue and my PC also is registered as producer. However, another Spring App on the machine should be configured as a listener. So far it is not working. ActiveMQ is listening on the default ports.

My JMS config for the sender:

```java
package at.dkepr.queueservice;

import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import javax.jms.Queue;

@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public Queue queue(){
        return new ActiveMQQueue("indexing-queue");
    }
}
```

And this is the consumer:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import at.dkepr.entity.UserSearchEntity;

@Component
@EnableJms
public class JmsConsumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsConsumer.class);
    
    @JmsListener(destination = "indexing-queue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(UserSearchEntity user){
        logger.info(user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

In the `application.propertiers` I have added the necessary properties:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

Also the `UserSearchEntity` implements `Serializable`.

To the best of my knowledge for this setup I should not even need a config for the consumer. Never the less, I added one.

```java
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;
  
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
      ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
      activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
      return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }
  
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
      factory.setConcurrency("1-3");
      return factory;
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error logs. Unfortunately, it is simply doing nothing.

This is a screenshot from the ActiveMQ web console with the enqueued messages:
[image]
My consuming application was running when I took this screenshot, but the broker clearly does not recognize it since the "Number of Consumers" is `0`.

Edit:
I just tried adding the Listener to the same Spring Application where the Producer is. Surprinsingly, the Listener connected fine. It seems like the problem lies in the different Spring Applications. However, i used the same `application.properties` for both Spring Apps. The Config File is the same too.

Comment: Yes indeed I did. It is not recognized though.

Comment: Added the properties. I left the ActiveMQ config on default. So it is listening on the default ports.

Answer (score 1):

To everyone having the same problem:

For me it was a simple problem with folder structure. For some reason the `Application.java` for the consumer service was in a subfolder. After i moved the `Application.java` one folder up, the connection to the ActiveMQ worked.